# Repeat a vector 3, 2, 1 time

Tags: r, repeat

I wanted to repeat a vector which contain 11 elements 3, 2 and 1 time and tried the following awkward code which gave me what I wanted (a vector of 66. How could I do that in a better way?

```
myd<-paste(letters[1:11])
mye<-rep(myd,each =3)
myf<-rep(myd,each =2)
myg<-rep(myd,each =1)
myh<-c(mye,myf,myg)

length(myh)
[1] 66
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `sapply` and `unlist`:

```
dat = unlist(sapply(3:1, function(x) rep(myd, each = x)))
all.equal(dat, myh)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `sapply`:

`unlist(sapply(3:1,function(x)rep(myd,each=x)))`

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a serious entrant. Just wanted to show that the `paste()` operation to `myd` was entirely superfluous, and that you can get patterned selection from sequences:

```
mye <-rep( letters[1:11], each =3)
myh <-c(mye, mye[c(TRUE,TRUE, FALSE)] , mye[c(TRUE,FALSE, FALSE)] )
```

The c(TRUE,TRUE, FALSE) and c(TRUE,FALSE, FALSE) will get recycled by `"["` so that every third item is omitted in the first case and every third item is selected en the second case.

Comment: Thanks All for this elegant code. Although the codes of Paul and zx8754 are essentially the same I will accept Paul's as his was the first response.